# URL in menu doesn't work because of JavaScript. How to solve this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, menu, smooth-scrolling

I'm working on a new website for my company, based on a basic template. Everything is in dutch, but you will understand my problem.

The homepage has a onepage navigation with smooth scrolling to different anchors. It works very neat. Now I created a [subpage](http://redesign.prsocial.nl/socialmedia.html), based on my homepage, where I want to have the same thing. By clicking on the menu buttons, there is smooth scrolling up and down. That works.

The subpage I'm talking is this one: http://redesign.prsocial.nl/socialmedia.html

The problem is on my subpage: I added a 'Home' button in the menu which should lead back to the homepage (index.html). When I click this Home button, nothing happens. I think it's a JS problem, but I can't figure out what it is exactly. I got it to work by deleting the smooth scrolling part, but I need both to work.

The other subpages aren't scripted correct yet, so I need only feedback on the subpage I linked to.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Firstly, fix error in console (init method)

Comment: the home button's event propagation was probably stopped.

Comment: if you could exclude the home in the smooth anchor script, that might do the trick

Comment: i think it must be preventDefault() function stopping it from navigating to other pages